# Passing an array of ID's from Swift URLSession to PHP for an SQL query?

Tags: php, swift, urlsession

I have an iOS application which has an array of ID's. These ID's are all numbers:

```
var ids = [Int]() //Id array in my TableView
ids = basketStruct.getAllIds() //Pulling the array of ID's from my basket model.
print("This is how PHP sees the POST") //Debugging purposes
print(self.ids)
print("This is how PHP sees the POST")
basketServer.ids = self.ids //Passing the ID's to my URLSession.
```

The URLSession handles the array in the following way:

```
var ids = [Int]()
func downloadItems() {
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    let postParameters = "ids="+String(describing: ids)
}
```

I've refrained from posting anymore of the URLSession class as it's probably unnecessary.

Now My XCode console is as follows:

```
This is how PHP sees the POST
[1,5,7,8]
This is how PHP sees the POST
Data downloaded
Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "No value." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=No value.}
```

I get no results returned. However, If I change all of my ID arrays to the type NSArray and run, I get results returned, as long as my array contains just 1 ID.  The second I add more than 1 ID to the array I get the same error.

Now, over on my php, if I change everything to GET rather than POST and directly enter some values in my URL bar and go to the page in a browser, everything works as it should. I get a nice JSON format response with all the ID's listed in my URL bar.

If I change everything back to POST, then access my apache error log files after trying to run my app, they say the following:

```
[Thu Feb 22 20:51:42.873663 2018] [:error] [pid 18793] [client 192.168.1.46:60790] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '[1])' at line 1 in /var/www/api/DbOperation.php:92\nStack trace:\n#0 /var/www/api/DbOperation.php(92): PDO->prepare('SELECT * FROM `...')\n#1 /var/www/api/Basket.php(14): DbOperation->basket('[1, 5, 7, 8]')\n#2 {main}\n  thrown in /var/www/api/DbOperation.php on line 92
```

I know this problem is broad and consists of many parts, but I'm stuck :( Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

P.S - Incase anybody wants to see it, here is my PHP code:

This is the PHP page my URLSession goes too:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/DbOperation.php';

$ids = $_POST["ids"];

$db = new DbOperation();
$json = $db->basket($ids);

}
```

Here is DbOperation:

```
    public function basket($ids) {
    require dirname(__FILE__) .  '/../../dbconnect.php';
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `Menu` WHERE `ID` IN ($ids)";
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->fetchAll();
    echo json_encode($result);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the PHP exception output you can see that the basket function is called with a string like this:

```
DbOperation->basket('[1, 5, 7, 8]')
```

Therefore, the PHP code will generate this SQL:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `Menu` WHERE `ID` IN ($ids)";
```

Which is:

```
SELECT * FROM `Menu` WHERE `ID` IN ([1, 5, 7, 8])
```

This is not valid SQL.

You can make this work by converting the $ids string into a format that will work in SQL.

```
// Remove '[' and ']' characters
$inValues = str_replace(['[',']'], '', $ids);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `Menu` WHERE `ID` IN ($inValues)";
```

Now you will get:

```
SELECT * FROM `Menu` WHERE `ID` IN (1, 5, 7, 8)
```

Comment: This is vulnerable to SQL injections.

Comment: I love you. I understand the point from ishegg, I was already aware this was open to an injection attack, I just couldn't understand why it wasn't working as expected. I will mark you as the answer. Thankyou for such a clear explanation.